# Image upload using JSP/Servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to upload image using my jsp and save this image to mysql database. I have this code

```
<form  method="POST"  class="registrations" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                    <div>
                        <span>Title :</span> <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="255" size="40" placeholder="e.g.(Update on ALert Status and Activity of Mayon Volcano, etc..)" required /><br />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Overview:</span>
                        <textarea rows="15" cols="75%" name="overview" required placeholder="Type a simple topic description..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Select an Image:</span>
                        <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/bmp"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Actions Taken:</span>
                        <textarea rows="15" cols="75%" name="action" required placeholder="Type a simple topic description..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btns">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send Report" /><input type="reset" value="Reset Fields" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

In my servlet I have this

```
Map<String, String> errors = SevereAssignContent.validate(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty())
        {
            jsp.forward(req, resp);
            return;
        }
SevereBulletinItems emsItem = (SevereBulletinItems) req.getAttribute("emsItem");
        new SevereWeatherDAO().create(emsItem);
        String msg = "Severe Weather Bullerin Report Submitted!";
        resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/pagasa/severe-weather-bulletin?msg=" + msg + "");
```

My SevereAssignContent Class

```
public class SevereAssignContent
{
    static ServletConfig conf;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Map<String, String> validate(HttpServletRequest req) 
    {
        SevereBulletinItems emsItem = new SevereBulletinItems();
        HashMap<String, String> errors = new HashMap<String, String>();
        req.setAttribute("errors", errors);
        req.setAttribute("emsItem", emsItem);




        try
        {

            String filePath = conf.getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator;
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            factory.setRepository(new File(filePath));


            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(req);

            for (FileItem item : items)
            {
                if (item.isFormField())
                {

                    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();

                    if (fieldname.equals("title"))
                        emsItem.setTitle(item.getString());
                    else if (fieldname.equals("overview"))
                        emsItem.setSituation(item.getString());
                    else if (fieldname.equals("action"))
                        emsItem.setAction(item.getString());

                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] data = item.get();
                    data = item.get();
                    if (data.length > 0)
                    {
                        Blob blob;
                        try
                        {
                            blob = new SerialBlob(data);
                            emsItem.setImage(blob);
                        }
                        catch (SerialException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (SQLException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

And my create statement

```
public void create(SevereBulletinItems item) throws IOException
    {
        Long id = getUniqueId();
        item.setReportId(id);

        java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        Connection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = getConnection();
            String sql = "insert into severeweatherbulletin values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setLong(1, id.longValue());
            statement.setString(2, item.getTitle());
            statement.setTimestamp(3, date);
            statement.setString(4, item.getSituation());
            statement.setBlob(5, item.getImage());
            statement.setString(6, item.getAction());
            statement.setLong(7, 1);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            close(statement, connection);
        }
    }
```

Now When I click submit, none of my inserted items saved in my database. Why? THanks

Comment: I don't see an execute line in your code.

Comment: What execute line @hd1 ?

Comment: There's no database code shown.

Comment: I already updated my post @hd1

Comment: Will further need getConnection()

Comment: getconnection doesnt have any issues because I am using it all the time...

Comment: Basically, what I'm wondering is if you need connection.commit() or not